# Temperature Converter (IF ELSE conditions) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am creating a Temperature Converter out of JavaScript. So far only the Celsius conversion works when the user inputs that first. I am just having trouble figuring out how to structure the other if statements.

```
  var conversionC;
  var conversionF;
  var conversionK;

  if ( celsius.value != "" ) {
     conversionF = document.getElementById("celsius").value * 9 / 5 + 32;
     document.getElementById("fahrenheit").value = Math.round(conversionF);
  } 

  else if ( fahrenheit.value != "" ){
     conversionC = (document.getElementById("fahrenheit").value - 32) * 5 / 9;
     document.getElementById("celsius").value = Math.round(conversionC);
  }

  if ( kelvin.value != "" ){
     conversionC = document.getElementById("celsius").value - -273;
     document.getElementById("kelvin").value = Math.round(conversionC);
  }
```

I only want to keep the one Convert button that I have, and still have it work when the user decides to input a Fahrenheit or Kelvin first.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Here is a JSFiddle of my program so far: 
https://jsfiddle.net/2sharkp/kw2sr1wx/

Thanks!

Comment: Well one problem is that the first if condition `if ( celsius.value != "" )` will always be true, because your `celsius` variable holds a number, and numbers don't have a `.value` property so what you're actually testing is `if(undefined != "")`. You need to test whether `document.getElementById("celsius").value != ""`. Another problem is that you default all the inputs to `0`, so testing them for an empty string doesn't quite make sense. (Although you probably do want to let the user enter a `0`, so I'm not sure how you could handle that with only one Convert button.)

Comment: Nothing wrong with an "if, else if, else if" series. Or an "if, else if, else".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your JSFiddle, you are taking each value and converting it into a float with `parseFloat`.

This means that when you hit `if ( celsius.value != "" )`, you are calling `.value` on a number, which is `undefined`. So you're really calling `if ( undefined != "" )`, which is true, and your first `if` block will always execute.

I'm assuming that your intention is to take the most recently edited field and use that for the conversion. I would recommend using a flag to indicate which field was last edited.

https://jsfiddle.net/camEdwards/chyg4ws1/

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what I needed. I am in an accelerated intro to HTML, CSS and JS course. We just got introduced to JS last class. I have a good handle with it so far, was just struggling with the logic on this. I really appreciate with how readable your code was as well!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
        let cels = document.getElementById('cels');
        let fahr = document.getElementById('fahr');
        cels.addEventListener('input', function(){
            let f = (this.value * 9/5) +32;
            if(!Number.isInteger){
                return f.toFixed(2);
            }
            fahr.value = f;
        });
        fahr.addEventListener('input', function(){
            let c = (this.value - 32) * 5/9;
            if(!Number.isInteger){
                return c.toFixed(2);
            }
            cels.value = c;
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).